# Push cells down together automatically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I got my data from Google Analytics and then format them in another sheet to make them more organised, sort of like a report. But I also need it to update automatically, so when there is new information/line pops up, the entire row below it will push down and everything will stay organised.

The concept is sort of like this https://superuser.com/questions/458958/push-cell-down-automatically-in-excel-2010-table. For example, I have [this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxij9.jpg), and as new information from Google Analytics update new information, in this case, new campaign from bing/cpc, I want it to be included and google/cpc and its campaign HP1 will be automatically pushed down.

I asked the questions in the Google sheet forum but was told that this is a script problem. Please help me if you know the solution to this problem

Comment: During updating you might take care of ensuring that the row is still present or just automatically recreate the new document with the added last row.

Comment: @flob Hi, I want the row to be still present. I edited the post to make my problem clearer. If you think something, please let me know!

Comment: Sorry, I have no precise idea, I just wanted to help you to get your question more readable and appealing to anyone who might help you.